# Find a column which subtracts another column

Tags: sql

In sql-server, There are three column in same table,i want to make Column_C from Column_A and Column_B
i want to get in same table in sql

```
 Column_A  Column_B Column_C
    1,2,3,4      2,3
     1,2,3        1



    Column_A  Column_B Column_C
     1,2,3,4      2,3  1,4
     1,2,3        1    2,3
```

Comment: Please normalize your schema before it is not too late :)

Comment: You should not store comma separated values in a single column.

Comment: Wait, I have so many questions.

Comment: I have more than one elements in a single cell with comma seperator

Comment: Having more than one element in a single cell with comma seperator breaks one of the cardinal rules of database design.

Comment: these are  varchar

Comment: Learn database design.  That will be a nightmare later on.  Even now you can't even do stuffs.  What's the point of storing data in a certain way if you can't do anything with it.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Postgres, you can install the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) extension, then the solution is as simple as:

```
select column_a, 
       column_b, 
       array_to_string(
          string_to_array(column_a,',')::int[] - string_to_array(column_b,',')::int[]
       , ',') as column_c
from badly_designed_table
```

despite the horrible design.

`string_to_array(column_a,',')::int[]` converts the string to an array.

The intarray extensions provides the `-` operator that removes elements from the first array that are contained in the second.

`array_to_string()` then converts the array back to a string.

Comment: Error: For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name

Comment: @Biddut: which database product are you using? Sounds as if you are not using Postgres

Answer (score 0):

I'm very unsure what the actual table looks like or the columns for that matter... But I'll give you a general response for now and you can let me know if you need something else:

```
SELECT (ColumnA - ColumnB) AS Column C
FROM tablename
```

But since your table isn't normalized, this is very confusing. As well, you should never store multiple values separated by a comma in your table, because you can do it, but it'll make SQL development SOOOO much harder.

Comment: Also, not sure whether you are adding, subtracting, multiplying, dividing, or what is happening with ColumnA and ColumnB.

Comment: Error: The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. It replaces Column_B's string present in Column_A with an empty string. It also deals with potential double commas and leading/trailing commas

```
SELECT Column_A,
       Column_B,
       LTRIM(
         RTRIM(
           REPLACE(
             REPLACE(Column_A,
                     Column_B,
                     ''),
             ',,',
             ','),
           ','),
         ',') AS Column_C
  FROM Table1
```

This is correct for Oracle SQL. If you are using a different DBMS, I think you just need to use the corresponding TRIM syntax.

Comment: Error: The rtrim function requires 1 argument(s).

Comment: @Biddut which DBMS are you using?

Comment: sql database  @Alex Zen

Comment: @Biddut "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database"

Comment: @Alex Zen Thanks